# ¿Como puedo re-establecer el acceso a mi bases de datos a como viene por defecto?

Tags: base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, ubuntu, localhost

Por motivos X le puse clave a la base de datos, pero no recuerdo cuál es, así que si me pueden dar consejo o me pueden decir como la puedo formatear como quien dice se lo agradecería, estoy usando Ubuntu 20.04 [image]

Answer (score 1):

Primero hay que detener el servidor MySQL:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Despues iniciar la configuracion mysqld:

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

En algunos casos necesitas crear el archivo mysqld primero:

```
sudo mkdir -v /var/run/mysqld && sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

Inicia el servidor MySQL:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Si quieres volver a poner una nueva contraseña, ingresa al servidor MySQL como root:

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

Ejecuta el siguiente comando reemplazando TUNUEVOPASSWORD con el password que quieres colocar:

```
UPDATE
  mysql.user
SET
  Password = PASSWORD('TUNUEVOPASSWORD')
WHERE
  User = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

En algunas versiones si no existe la columna password debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('TUNUEVOPASSWORD') WHERE user='root';
```

Comment: cuando trato de seguir los pasos me sale que no se encuentra mysql en el computador pero me sale que si lo tengo instalado cuando ejecuto el "sudo service --status-all"

Comment: mm posiblemente se instalo mariadb en vez de mysql, ejecuta sudo service mysql status y revisa si dice maria o mysql